# Formatting data array correctly for Highcharts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

Seem to be struggling to get my data in the correct format for use with a highchart's pie chart.

If I force the data as follows my graph appears so I know I've done the integration correctly:

```
data: [
      ['Test', 30],
      ['Other', 70],
      ]
```

But when I try and use my actual data, it ain't working.

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
data: <%= Location.browsers.map { |o| [o.type, o.count] }.inspect %>
```

Have also tried:

```
data: <%= Location.browsers.map { |o| "#{o.type}, #{o.count}" }.to_json %>
```

The first one gives me a result like this:

```
"[[\"Safari\", 6448], [\"Microsoft\", 5253], [\"Microsoft-CryptoAPI\", 5185], [\"Dalvik\", 3870], [\"Chrome\", 3701], [\"Mozilla\", 3239], [\"Android\", 2285], [\"Windows-Update-Agent\", 2018], [\"Internet Explorer\", 1843], [\"Firefox\", 1459]]"
```

Which looks ok.

What's the correct way to run this query?

Comment: Pretty sure the `inspect` is messing things up. Have you tried `Location.browsers.map { |o| [o.type, o.count] }`?.

Comment: Yeah, was following this asciicast: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/223-charts Have removed though, still no joy..

Comment: Just to check that the problem is on Ruby side, not JS side, could you show the *generated* js part of your html page with non-working call to `Highcharts.Chart`, as it finally appears in webpage source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rb
data: <%= raw Location.browsers.map { |o| [o.type, o.count] } %>
```

or

```rb
data: <%= raw Location.browsers.map { |o| [o.type, o.count] }.to_s %>
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

## I

```
"[[\"A\", 10], [\"B\", 30], [\"C\", 0], [\"D\", -10]]"
```

## II

```
[["A", 10], ["B", 30], ["C", 0], ["D", -10]]
```

I & II Are not the same

I is a **`String`** while II is a javascript **`Array<Array<Object>>`**

In your case the first one is the [`stringify`-ed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) version of the second. You just need to do the reverse process of this to get back the `Array` from the `String` using [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or [`JSON.parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836466%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

I don't have first hand experience with Ruby, but my guess is something like this will do the job

```
data: $.parseJSON(<%= Location.browsers.map { |o| [o.type, o.count] }.inspect %>)
```

**[Parsing string data into JSON @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/5resH/)**